# Ways to Include Doctrine2 Entity Manager With Simple Design Patterns Instead of a Framework

Tags: php, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, dns, doctrine-orm

I am just starting out with Doctrine2 and I noticed that it is highly built around design patterns so I wanted to get some ideas on how to create an application around Doctrine2 using **more** design patterns.

For example, all Doctrine2 applications will contain a file or class similar to

```
require '/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
    Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;

//...class loading and config stuff goes here


$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_sqlite',
    'path' => 'database.sqlite'
);

$em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

Now a framework like Symfony will make it easy to access your EntitityManager and then spit that information out to the screen.

**However**, some applications are simple enough where an entire framework like Symfony is not necessary. You just want to be able to access your data and then spit it out to a view/ page.

Can you provide an example for a good design pattern that will make this possible?

I am looking forward to seeing some interesting examples and ideas, and in general just good solid Object Oriented PHP toughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a [DI Container](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/29/pimple-the-small-dependency-injection-container-for-php-5-3). If you could provide a little more insight into how your application works I could provide a more specific solution.

`some applications are simple enough where an entire framework like Symfony is not necessary`

If that is the case, then Doctrine 2 is likely overkill as well.

**Good resources**
Here are some good resources if you want to learn more about DDD and design patterns:

- [Giorgio Sironi](http://css.dzone.com/users/piccoloprincipe)
- [Federico Cargnelutti](http://blog.fedecarg.com/)
- [Martin Fowler's Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa)
- [Integrating Zend Framework and Doctrine 2](http://www.cobbweb.me/2010/11/integrate-doctrine-2-zend-framework-application/)

Comment: I have to disagree with your third paragraph. I think a solid domain model is always a good thing... I am not looking for application specific examples here, just general ideas like the DI container you mentioned, but more specific examples are welcome.

Comment: Added some resources to my answer